# Getting error py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty in spark streaming

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am trying to get data from kafka using spark streaming with python API.

Any one have any idea about why this error is coming

i am getting below error:
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shadan/softwares/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1035, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shadan/softwares/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/shadan/softwares/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving`enter code here`

Comment: I have the same question, I added more details [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171431/structured-streaming-error-py4j-protocol-py4jnetworkerror-answer-from-java-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171431/structured-streaming-error-py4j-protocol-py4jnetworkerror-answer-from-java-side)